# Is a there exception if you ask for a integer and do not get an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I am trying to make a program where you enter an integer, but if you do not enter an integer, handle it with an exception. However I can not find any exceptions for integers on the internet.

```
### TECH SUPPORT ###

while True:
    try:
       i = int(input('Enter an INTEGER: '))
    except [INT EXCEPTION HERE]:
        print("You must enter an INTEGER, not any other format of data")
```

-
Does anyone know an exception if you ask for an integer input and do not get an integer?

Comment: What exception did you get when you tried to enter an invalid integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always try it in interpreter to see which error gets raised:

```
>>> int('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Now that you know that it is `ValueError`, just change your code:

```
while True:
    try:
       i = int(input('Enter an INTEGER: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an INTEGER, not any other format of data")
    else:
        break # to exit the while loop
```

Comment: So I can make any error and check the exception the python handler gives me?

Comment: yes @user10072727 , unless your error has permanent side effects like deleting a file, you're safe. And those instances are generally well documented.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `ValueError`

More about python [try except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Go through the [builtin exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions) list, which will help you.

Also, when an builtin `exception` is raised like so -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

You can see

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`

So python raises`ValueError` and this is the exception you need to use.

Comment: I've closed the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ValueError" exception

```
while True:
try:
   i = int(input('Enter an INTEGER: '))
except ValueError:
    print("You must enter an INTEGER, not any other format of data")
```